# Grails 3 and Json: "Request method 'POST' not supported"

Tags: json, spring, grails, grails-3.0

I'm porting a working webapp from Grails 2.3 to 3.0.1. When I post the Json string {"command":"ping"} to the server i get the following result:

```
{"timestamp":1429380750958,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/rps/request"}
```

Here's the controller:

```
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject
class RequestController {
    def jsonManagerService
    def index() {
        JSONObject json = request.JSON
        if(!json){
            render "{json or gtfo}"
            return
        }
        render jsonManagerService.parseJson(json)
    }
}
```

Here's the JsonManagerService:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject
@Transactional
class JsonManagerService {
    def parseJson(JSONObject o) {
        switch  (o.command){
            case("ping"):
                return '{"result":"pong"}'
                break;
            default:
                return '{"result":"unknown command"}'
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my UrlMappings.groovy (it's the default one):

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

It looks like a Spring related issue. All the search on this matter provided no results. Any idea?

Edit: thanks @dmahapatro, added UrlMappingsgroovy. Corrected the controller, dumb mistake, but result is still the same.

Comment: `def jsonManagerService` is dependency injection which should be at the class level inside the controller. Can you also show what is the url mapping. You have to make sure `/rps/request` which redirects to index action is able to handle POST requests.

Comment: I updated the question, same result. The UrlMappings is the default one, as it was in the previously working Grails 2.4.3 app.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the accepted actions on the method. 

static allowedMethods = [index: "POST" ].  Else try changing the request to a GET to verify if the request actually reaches the controller.

Comment: The controller is reached because if I render my page on the browser I get "{json or gtfo}". Adding  static allowedMethods = [index: 'POST'] at class level in my controller leads to the same "Method not allowed" error.

Comment: Hi, how are you posting your json to your web app, curl ?

Comment: @MiguelElMerendero , have you found a solution? I have same warns in the log after migration to grails 3.1.15